# SKAction Waiting for Completion

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a SpriteKit game and I'm trying to get an SKCameraNode to follow the player node. However, when I access the position property of the player node after using an SKAction to move it, the position after running the action is the same as the position before running it. Here is my scene code:

```
func updateMap(playerX: Int, playerY: Int) {
    player.coordinates = CGPoint(x: highlightedTile.tileX, y: highlightedTile.tileY)
    camera?.position = player.position
}
```

and the code from my `player` class:

```
var coordinates: CGPoint {
    didSet{
        let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: (coordinates.x) * 64 - 64, y: (coordinates.y) * 56 - 47), duration: NSTimeInterval(2.0))
        self.runAction(moveAction)
    }
}
```

SpriteKit does not update the `position` property of the player node until the action is complete. Therefore I want to wait until the animation has completed before updating the camera position. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You are querying the `position` property before the moving is completed...

Try this:

```
print(playerNode.position)

let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: (coordinates.x) * 64 - 64, y: (coordinates.y) * 56 - 47), duration: NSTimeInterval(2.0))
let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(3))

self.runAction(moveAction, completion: {
   print(playerNode.position)
})
```

Also note that I use `playerNode` variable, which should represent the player. Not sure what `self` is in your case though ( the player or the scene).

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity in my question. This code is part of my `player` class. `Player` has a property, `coordinates`, which represents the player's position on a map. This code fires when the `coordinates` property is changed. What I want to do is run code in my scene class, not the player class, once the player has moved. How can this be done?

Comment: @ATyshka What is the problem with what I have posted ? Does it prints the start and the end location of the player ?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion in stating my problem. I have updated my question.

Comment: @Whirlwind - just what I was looking for. Hope you're doing well. I decided to finally dive more back into Swift and continue that RPG game I started all those years ago. Now I just need to figure out how process multiple hit animations sequentially during player/enemy turns...  :(

Comment: @sangony Hey, sorry for the late answer. Glad to hear from you  :) Feel free to hit me up on email (its in my SO profile).